# Why does the function "sleep" only waits the time I tell it to when starting the proyect instead of after something before it already happened

Tags: c++, time, delay, sleep

the code waits 2 seconds and then writes "hello world goodbye world" instead of writing hello world and waiting 2 seconds to write goodbye world

btw this is the code:

```
cout<<"Hello World"; 
sleep(2.0);
cout<<" Goodbye World";
return 0;
```

Comment: Output is buffered; try `cout << "Hello!" << endl;` which flushes the internal buffer to output.

Comment: Nope.  The problem is not "sleep".  The problem is that the `cout` output is buffered.  The first string is stored in a buffer, and will not be physically transmitted to the device until you do `endl` or `flush` (or send a `'\n'` on a console).